# Auto resize of content on radSplitter

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, visual-studio-2010, telerik

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>

 <telerik:RadSplitter ID="RadSplitter1" runat="server" Width="800" Height="500">
      <telerik:RadPane ID="navigationPane" runat="server">
           Left Pane
      </telerik:RadPane>
      <telerik:RadSplitBar ID="RadSplitbar1" runat="server" CollapseMode="Forward">
      </telerik:RadSplitBar>
      <telerik:RadPane ID="contentPane" runat="server" PersistScrollPosition="False">
           Right Pane
               <div id="Map">
</div>
      </telerik:RadPane>
 </telerik:RadSplitter>
</form>
```

Hi i have this above code for my web application, so basically i need a help, I cant find tutorial on demo.telerik so I need your help. 
the slider is a bit too thick as compare to this website.
http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/splitter/examples/splitterorientation/defaultcs.aspx

2nd problem is if i drag the slider toward left, the content on the right panel did not enlarge and it stay the same
the content on the right panel is . some sort of liek there is not auto resize to fit the right panel

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand, the Splitbar is too thick?  You can control the width of the RadSplitBar by adding a SplitBarSize attribute to the telerik:RadSplitter element.
http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/splitter/radsplitbar-width-issue.aspx

Content in the RadPanes should resize automatically within the total space that you have allotted for the RadSplitter.  If you would like it to fill the screen and adjust with the window size, consider this demo:
http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/splitter/examples/resizewithwindow/defaultcs.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/window-troubleshooting-distorted-appearance.html. I think you have the same issue - some CSS from your page overriding the default settings so some element becomes larger than Telerik need it to be.

On resizing - set the div's size in percent and make sure the content inside is also in percent, e.g.:

```
<div id="Map" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
```